# Trying to compute the loss of an encoder/decoder model

Tags: python, pytorch

I am attempting to create an encoder/decoder model with mini-batch. I continue to encounter an errors stating:

*RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [32, 6]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!*

The traceback reveals something is wrong with the `y=self.linear(out)` but I am unsure what exactly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the model. Thank you.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
from sliding_window import sliding_window
from training_datasets import get_training_datasets_batch
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)


class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers=1):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size,num_layers=num_layers,batch_first=True)
    def forward(self, x):
        flat = x.view(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], self.input_size)
        out,h = self.gru(flat)
        return out, h


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size=6, num_layers=1):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.output_size = output_size

        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size=input_size,hidden_size=hidden_size,num_layers=num_layers,batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.ReLU = nn.ReLU()
    def forward(self, x, h):
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        out, h = self.gru(x, h)
        out = out.squeeze(1)
        print(out.shape)
        y = self.linear(out)
        print(y.shape)
        y = self.ReLU(y)
        return y,h

class EncoderDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, input_size=6, output_size=6):
        super(EncoderDecoder, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.encoder = Encoder(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size)
        self.decoder = Decoder(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, output_size=output_size)

    def train_model(self, ts, epochs, target_len, features, batch_size=64, test_len=288, method = 'teacher_forcing', tfr = 0.5, lr = 0.01, dynamic_tf=False):
        X,Y= sliding_window(ts, features=288, target_len=target_len)

        x_train, x_val, x_test, y_train, y_val, y_test = get_training_datasets_batch(X,Y, features, test_len=test_len, batch_size=batch_size)
        losses = np.full(epochs,np.nan)
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(filter(lambda x: x.requires_grad, self.parameters()),
                                  lr=lr)
        criterion = nn.MSELoss()
        for e in range(epochs):
            print('Starting epoch {}'.format(e))
            x_train_data = iter(x_train)
            y_train_data = iter(y_train)
            x_val_data = iter(x_val)
            y_val_data = iter(y_val)
            x_train_shape = list(x_train)[0].shape
            # predicted = torch.zeros(target_len,batch_size,x_train_shape[2])
            # print(predicted.shape)
            loss=0
            for x_train_in in x_train_data:
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                x_train_in = Variable(x_train_in)
                y_train_in = Variable(next(y_train_data).transpose(0,1))
                _, enc_h = self.encoder(x_train_in)
                dec_in = x_train_in[:,-1,:]
                dec_h = enc_h
                
                if method == 'recursive':
                    for t in range(target_len):
                        dec_out, dec_h = self.decoder(dec_in, dec_h)
                        predicted = dec_out
                        dec_in = dec_out
                        loss += criterion(predicted,y_train_in[t])

                loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
                optimizer.step()
```

Comment: My bet is on `retain_graph=True`, which is usually cumbersome to handle and it can raise these kind of errors.

Comment: I've used it without `retain_graph=True` and it results in another error.
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

Comment: Did you set it to `True` because of this error, or because you effectively need it? Anyway, I would suggest moving `train_model` out of the `EncoderDecoder` class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case was the loss.backward(retain_graph=True). The code started working after adding the line `loss=0`. The loss value continues to increase and needs to be reset.

```
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
loss=0
```